# What is wrong with this subproduct? I think I have not been able to use OR in the sumproduct

Tags: excel

Please see the formula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(tEnvironment[Resultatenhet]=[@Resultatenhet]);--(tEnvironment[Anst fr o m]<=[@Period]);1*--(tEnvironment[Anst t o m]="")+--(tEnvironment[Anst t o m]>=DATE(YEAR([@Period]);MONTH([@Period])+1;0)))
```

I try to count the number of occurances when:

```
tEnvironment[Resultatenhet]=[@Resultatenhet]
AND
tEnvironment[Anst fr o m]<=[@Period]
AND
(tEnvironment[Anst t o m]="" OR tEnvironment[Anst t o m]>=DATE(YEAR([@Period]);MONTH([@Period])+1;0)))
```

But it doesn't quite work. Some error searhing lead me to beleve that some values are counted twice. What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the potential overcounting is that the two expressions which are being summed in the final clause, i.e.:

`[Anst t o m]=""`

and

`[Anst t o m]>=DATE(YEAR([@Period]),MONTH([@Period])+1,0)`

are not mutually exclusive, since Excel considers the null string "" to be "greater" than any numerical.

Hence summation of the two above clauses will lead to a result of 2 for any row for which the *Anst t o m* field contains a null string (and of course which satisfies the other conditions).

One way to resolve this is to make that clause comparative, viz (I have also tidied up some of your superfluous coercions):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--([Resultatenhet]=[@Resultatenhet]),--([Anst fr o m]<=[@Period]),--(([Anst t o m]="")+([Anst t o m]>=DATE(YEAR([@Period]),MONTH([@Period])+1,0))>0))`

What's more, if, as seems to be the case, all of your blank cells contain the null string "" (and so are not technically empty), then, via the logic given above, you can use simply:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--([Resultatenhet]=[@Resultatenhet]),--([Anst fr o m]<=[@Period]),--([Anst t o m]>=DATE(YEAR([@Period]),MONTH([@Period])+1,0)))`

since the single, final clause will also be satisfied by any null strings, and hence no additional, explicit test for blankness is required.

Regards